# Enabling and disabling indexes in plsql having performance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am disabling and enabling the indexes before inserting data into staging table and before inserting data into the destination table(using MERGE statement) respectively. While the functionality is working fine my program takes too much time, as long as 10 hours to complete. This is how i'm doing in the code :

1. first disabling indexes of staging table..
2. load data into stage table using SQL*Loader..
3. enable the indexes of staging table..
4. insert data into destination table using MERGE(MERGE to dest. table using staging table.)
5. update errors, if any, to the staging table

NOTE : The staging table already has nearly 400 million rows. I was trying to insert 23 rows into staging and eventually destination table. The insertion into staging table is quick(till step 2) but rebuilding indexes and further on from step 3 is taking 10 hours.!!

Is my approach correct? How do i improve the performance?

Comment: If your inserts are small, I would recommend not play with the index

Comment: If you are rebuilding indexes, use PARALLEL to make it faster provided you have enough CPU. Post rebuild alter index to NOPARALLEL. This would make index rebuilds faster. If you want only 23 rows to be loaded into destination table, better select and insert it directly from staging table into destination table. Why go for a merge?

Comment: Do you need indexes on the staging table?

Comment: How long does it take **without** dropping and rebuilding the indexes?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the NOTE; does it mean that - when you inserted 23 sample rows into the staging table - further steps (3, 4, 5) take 10 hours to complete? Or is "10 hours" pair of 400 million rows? I'm thinking of a high water mark; if possible, try to **DROP** staging table before loading session (step 1), and in step 3 **CREATE INDEXES**.

Comment: Are you inserting 400 millions rows ? or only 23 ? Your approach make sense only if you are adding 400 millions rows to the table. Rebuilding index is a massive CPU process.

Comment: @APC - Without dropping and rebuilding indexes the loading (step2) itself takes 8 hours and then remaining 3,4,5 steps takes 10 hours, total 18 hours.!!

Comment: @Littlefoot - Yes, when i tried to insert 23 rows, the further steps 3,4,5 takes 10 hours to complete. Since staging table has 400 million rows already in it the rebuilding indexes is taking time. And no, can't drop table as per design. any other workaround.?

Comment: @FábioGalera - No, the table already has 400M rows (i was just trying to give an estimate of the number of rows present). For the purpose of testing i am inserting 23 rows, in real time the number of rows inserting at one point of time could be massive. Also, i cannot delete the staging table and re-create, What is the workaround that you would suggest ?

Comment: Are you saying that staging table grows? Now it contains 400 million rows, but during the next "importing" session you'll add some more? If that's so, well, that looks *wrong* to me. There's the destination table which is supposed to contain all data you need. Staging table is something "temporary", that can be deleted before every session so that it contains only small amount of data which is then transferred into the destination table. Why would you keep that much rows in staging table? If that's a *must*, consider using yet another, *true* staging (temporary) table.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the facts you mentioned:**
 1. Table already have 400M;
 2. It's a Staging table;
 3. New inserts can be massive;
 4. You didn't specify if you need the rows in Staging, so I will cover as you need it.

**Scenario** I would create 3 tables:
TABLE_STAGING
TABLE_DESTINATION
TABLE_TEMP

1- First disable indexes of TABLE_TEMP;

2- Load data into TABLE_TEMP using SQL*Loader (read about APPEND
    hint and Direct Load)

3- Enable the indexes in your TABLE_TEMP;

4- Insert data into TABLE_DESTINATION using MERGE on TABLE_TEMP;

5- Insert data into TABLE_STAGING from TABLE_TEMP - here you correct
    the errors you found:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_STAGING SELECT * FROM TABLE_TEMP;
```

6- Truncate table TABLE_TEMP;

Rebuilding index in 400M rows all the time is not ideal, it's a massive CPU work to check each value in the row to build the index. Staging tables should be empty all the table, or use temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot fabio, i'll try this approach, i think this should work.